# Joomla K2 show extra fields on generic.php

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla-k2

We are developing a website based on k2. For this we make use of the extrafields to give an article an specific css class.

But when we use the archive extension this class is not applied and we get an error.

This is the error we get

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/recall/domains/domain.com/public_html/templates/mytemplate/html/com_k2/generic.php
>   on line 19

This is the code

```
<!-- START: Call to prepare extra fields -->
<?php  
//convertArray to use ids as key
$extrafields = array();
foreach($this->item->extra_fields as $item)
{    
$extrafields[$item->id] = $item->value;
}   
?>    
<!-- END: Call to prepare extra fields -->

<!-- Start K2 Generic (search/date) Layout -->
<div id="k2Container" class="genericView<?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page-id')); ?> nieuwsarchief">

        <?php if($this->params->get('genericFeedIcon',1)): ?>
        <!-- RSS feed icon -->
        <ul class="k2SendReceiveNews">
                <li class="legende_bestuur"><span>Bestuur</span></li>
                <li class="legende_regio"><span>Regio</span></li>
                <li class="legende_school"><span>School</span></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nieuws melden</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nieuws via e-mail ontvangen</a></li>
                <li class="rssfeed"><a href="<?php echo $this->feed; ?>" title="<?php echo JText::_('K2_SUBSCRIBE_TO_RSS'); ?>">
                        <span><?php echo JText::_('K2_SUBSCRIBE_TO_RSS'); ?></span>
                </a></li>
                <div class="clr"></div>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if($this->params->get('show_page_title')): ?>
        <!-- Page title -->
        <div class="componentheading<?php echo $this->params->get('pageclass_sfx')?>">
                <?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_title')); ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if(count($this->items)): ?>
        <div>
                <?php foreach($this->items as $item): ?>

                <!-- Start K2 Item Layout -->
                <div class="CatItem-<?php echo $extraFlds['Nieuwscategorie']; ?>">
                <?php
echo $item->extra_fields[11]->value;
?>

                        <div class="catItemContent catItemHeader">

                          <?php if($this->params->get('genericItemTitle')): ?>
                          <!-- Item title -->
                          <h3 class="catItemTitle">
                                <?php if ($this->params->get('genericItemTitleLinked')): ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>">
                                        <?php echo $item->title; ?>
                                </a>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                <?php echo $item->title; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                          </h3>
                          <?php endif; ?>
                          <?php if($this->params->get('genericItemDateCreated')): ?>
                                <!-- Date created -->
                                <span class="genericItemDateCreated">
                                        <?php echo JHTML::_('date', $item->created , JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC10')); ?>
                                </span>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <!-- End K2 Item Layout -->

                <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>

        <!-- Pagination -->
        <?php if($this->pagination->getPagesLinks()): ?>
        <div class="k2Pagination">
                <?php echo $this->pagination->getPagesLinks(); ?>
                <div class="clr"></div>
                <?php echo $this->pagination->getPagesCounter(); ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

</div>
<!-- End K2 Generic (search/date) Layout -->
```

---

I've found the solution myself.

This is the final code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @version     $Id: generic.php 1618 2012-09-21 11:23:08Z lefteris.kavadas $
 * @package     K2
 * @author      JoomlaWorks http://www.joomlaworks.net
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006 - 2012 JoomlaWorks Ltd. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU/GPL license: http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html
 */

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

?>

<!-- Start K2 Generic (search/date) Layout -->
<div id="k2Container" class="genericView<?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page-id')); ?> nieuwsarchief">

    <?php if($this->params->get('genericFeedIcon',1)): ?>
    <!-- RSS feed icon -->
    <ul class="k2SendReceiveNews">
        <li class="legende_bestuur"><span>Bestuur</span></li>
        <li class="legende_regio"><span>Regio</span></li>
        <li class="legende_school"><span>School</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nieuws melden</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nieuws via e-mail ontvangen</a></li>
        <li class="rssfeed"><a href="<?php echo $this->feed; ?>" title="<?php echo JText::_('K2_SUBSCRIBE_TO_RSS'); ?>">
            <span><?php echo JText::_('K2_SUBSCRIBE_TO_RSS'); ?></span>
        </a></li>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($this->params->get('show_page_title')): ?>
    <!-- Page title -->
    <div class="componentheading<?php echo $this->params->get('pageclass_sfx')?>">
        <?php echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_title')); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(count($this->items)): ?>
    <div>

        <?php foreach($this->items as $item): ?>

        <!-- START: Call to prepare extra fields -->
        <?php
        //convertArray to use ids as key
        $extrafields = array();
        foreach($item->extra_fields as $extraFlds)
        {    
        $extrafields[$extraFlds->id] = $extraFlds->value;
        }   
        ?>    
        <!-- END: Call to prepare extra fields -->

        <!-- Start K2 Item Layout -->
        <div class="CatItem-<?php echo $extrafields[11];?>">

            <div class="catItemContent catItemHeader">

              <?php if($this->params->get('genericItemTitle')): ?>
              <!-- Item title -->
              <h3 class="catItemTitle">
                <?php if ($this->params->get('genericItemTitleLinked')): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>">
                    <?php echo $item->title; ?>
                </a>
                <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $item->title; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
              </h3>
              <?php endif; ?>
              <?php if($this->params->get('genericItemDateCreated')): ?>
                <!-- Date created -->
                <span class="genericItemDateCreated">
                    <?php echo JHTML::_('date', $item->created , JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC10')); ?>
                </span>
                <?php endif; ?>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!-- End K2 Item Layout -->

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Pagination -->
    <?php if($this->pagination->getPagesLinks()): ?>
    <div class="k2Pagination">
        <?php echo $this->pagination->getPagesLinks(); ?>
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <?php echo $this->pagination->getPagesCounter(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
<!-- End K2 Generic (search/date) Layout -->
```

For the right value, find the corresponding id at the backend of k2 extra fields (on the right)

For me it was **id 11**

```
<?php echo $extrafields[11];?>
```

Comment: Seeing as generic.php is inside a folder called **templates**, try creating a new folder so that the path is like so: `mytemplate/html/com_k2/templates/generic.php`

Comment: I've done that as you can see on the error ;) The generic.php is called from the k2Archive module.

Comment: The template is working fine, only the extrafields are not processed.

Comment: Does it work without the template override?

Comment: It shows the extrafields, but I need one particular extra field to echo. Therefore I use the first few lines of code. When I paste this piece of code in the generic.php on the core file it also gives the same error.

Comment: I'm one step further now,

I moved the query within the <?php foreach($this->items as $item): ?>

Now the code works, but the rest is not working anymore

Comment: If your using a template override and the latest version of k2 make sure your template override is up to date as there was a major update to the extra fields section of k2 in V2.6.2!

Comment: I've updated my question with the answer ;)